# How to add meta_data to the a WooCommerce customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

And I am trying to update a customer which requires a PUT request to the server. Here is the code to initialize WooCommerce REST API:

```
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://example.com',
  consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});
```

This is the code that updates customer:

```
var data = {
 "meta_data":[
  {
  "key": "stores",
  "value": "food"
  }
 ],
 "first_name": "name"
}

WooCommerce.put('customers/5', data, function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

The above code updates the customers "first_name" but does not add anything to the "meta_data" section of the customer. Any ideas as to why?
Im guessing the PHP file does not update the meta data or is something wrong with my meta_data input format??? How can I update the meta_data of the customer?
I have also tried using legacy woo versions (eg. 'wc/v2', 'wc/v1') but those don't even update the first_name.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964640/woocommerce-customer-rest-api-meta-data-not-updating

Answer (score 0):

As you assumed, the input format of meta is wrong. For some reasons, double array is needed for updating meta data:

```
'meta_data' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => $meta_key,
                    'value' => $meta_value
                ))
 ))
```

See also here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/18810

You should have gotten an error like 'invalid input parameter' or sth similar. Please log not only the `res` but also the `err` in your code.