# How can I use the WooCommerce CLI to update a customer's metadata?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, api, woocommerce, command-line

I feel like I should be able to do

`sudo wp wc customer update 141 --meta_data="[{"key":"test_meta1","value":"test_meta_value"}]" --user=1`

However, this does not work.

The result I get is

`Success: Updated customer 141.`

However,
`sudo wp wc customer get 141 --fields=meta_data --user=1 | grep test_meta`

returns blank.

Almost certainly, I'm not providing the data in the right format, but I'm not sure what it is, or where its documented.

Possibly helpful links:
[How to add meta_data to the a WooCommerce customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264650/how-to-add-meta-data-to-the-a-woocommerce-customer)

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/18810

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/WC-CLI-Overview

Comment: On REST API, this works

`curl -X PUT https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/141 \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"meta_data": [{"key": "email_drip_seq","value": "TESTDRAGON"}]}' `

Comment: I also can't figure out a way to add metadata on the wp wc cli for the product metadata interface - eg 

 sudo wp wc product  create --name="test2" --sku="test2" --regular_price=10 --meta_data="[{"meta_data": [{"key": "email_drip_seq","value": "TESTDRAGON"}]}]" --user=1

silently ignores the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```
 --meta_data='[{"key": "test_meta1","value": "test_meta_value"}]'
```

eg

```
sudo wp wc customer update 141  --meta_data='[{"key": "test_meta1","value": "test_meta_value"}]' --user=1
```

or

```
sudo wp wc product  create --name="test4" --regular_price=10 --meta_data='[{"key": "test_meta1","value": "test_meta_value"}]' --user=1
```

will work